# Getting req.headers is undefined when trying to read from req object in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On page load, I try to fire off an authentication request if a token exists in local storage.

```
// utils.ts
const init = async () => {
    try {
        const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
            const { user } = await axios.get('/api/auth/load')

            console.log('user!', user);
        } else {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'];
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('There was an error with init: ', err);
    }
}
```

And my `pages/api/auth/load.ts` file:

```
export default async function load(req: TLoadUserRequest, res) {
    auth(req, res);
    const { id } = req.user;

    await connectDb();

    const user = await User.findById(id);

    return res.json(user);
}
```

The problem lies within my `auth.ts`, which throws an error,

```
TypeError: req.headers is not a function
```

Here it is:

```
// middleware/auth.ts
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from 'config';

export default (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers('x-auth-token');
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token. Authorization denied.' });

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
        req.user = decoded.user;
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is invalid' });
    }
};
```

When I use Node/Express, I don't get this error -- does NextJS' `req` object not have a `headers` property? How can I add it, so I can use it with axios like this?

Comment: `req` is a http request object only available on the server side so it makes sense that it works on Node/Express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit wrong for getting a header value.

```
req.headers('x-auth-token')
```

Should be

```
req.headers['x-auth-token']
```

Comment: In addition, I was getting undefined whilst using the square brackets... turns out it didn't like me capitalising the header's name. So yeah, check that. 

Answer (score 0):

I did it by the bad way, but, it works for me:

```
//Sending:
const config = {                
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${ElToken}` }
        };

        const resp = await axios.post("/api/nd-data", consulta, config);


//API:
    if (req.method === "POST") {

       const i = req.rawHeaders.indexOf('Authorization');
       const token = req.rawHeaders[i+1];
       console.log("token api: ", token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I'd to use some changes but this is how my code works in these two platforms.

In Node.js it worked with: `req.header('x-auth-token')`

In Next.js it worked with `req.headers['x-auth-token']`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31285837)

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs you should use `req.getHeader(<headerName>)`
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_getheader_name

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Next.js doesn't seem to support that. I get this error: `Property 'getHeader' does not exist on type 'NextApiRequest'`.